# Variance in Users in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have a situation where we have pulled the users in Google Analytics for each year (2013, 2014, 2015, 2016) and then users for the total span (2013-2016). We were anticipating having a significant variance between the sum of the individual years and the total from the multi-year pull (due to double counting a user who comes in 2013 AND 2014). However, that difference is less than 5%. That seems really low, given we have an over 40% return visitor rate each year. Any ideas what could lead to this?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics cookie lasts for 2 years if the user doesn't clear their browsing data, so perhaps that could be a major factor in reducing duplicate users across that timeframe.